# How to concat_ws primarykey(id) and date in a new column on same table?(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need add a new column named date_id by using concat_ws('-', curdate,id) on a same table, the id is a primarykey and auto_increment. 
How to do this?

I tried add a column and updated it. it worked, but when I insert some new row, the error showed Filed 'id' doesnot have a default value.
How to solve this?

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD date_id VARCHAR(50);
UPDATE table1 SET date_id = CONCAT_WS('-',date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d'),id);
```

### update question

I have created a table：

```
USE table_name;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gzsrieQA`(
   `id` INT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `record_id` VARCHAR(50),
   `date` date,
   `pro_name` VARCHAR(50),
   `error_info` VARCHAR(255),
   `error_describe` VARCHAR(255),
   `reason` VARCHAR(255),
   `solution` VARCHAR(255),
   `solution_file` BLOB,
     `solution_file_name` VARCHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 001;
UPDATE table_name SET record_id = CONCAT_WS('-','SRIE-DSJ-QA',date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d'),id);
```

When I insert into some new data, the result showed 'record_id' is null. it means I need a trigger? But the question is if I insert lots of data, the trigger is too slow.Is there any solution to solve this if I don't use trigger?
For example:

```
|id|record_id|name|
|-----|-----|-----|
|001| |ABC|
|002| |xyz|

# I want to get:
|id|record_id|name|
|-----|-----|-----|
|001|ABC001|ABC|
|002|xyz002|xyz|

# and when I insert into name=AAA, the result is:
|id|record_id|name|
|-----|-----|-----|
|001|ABC001|ABC|
|002|xyz002|xyz|
|003|aaa003|AAA|
```

THANKS!

Comment: use SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'table_name'.. it will give you auto increment value.

Comment: Note the information schema isn't race condition safe so you may get the same value twice. Also the obvious soultion of generated columns don't currently support references to the auto_increment column. So a trigger is your current option (don't know if it has a AI value limitation). In terms of slow, benchmark it.

Comment: Show us the `INSERT` statement, too.  Note that the `UPDATE` is not useful until _after_ the `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried MySQL and it allowed your statement however you can set a default and then remove it.

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.13    |
> ```

> ```
> create table table1 (id int auto_increment primary key);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into table1(id) values (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE table1 ADD date_id VARCHAR(50)  default '';
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 SET date_id = CONCAT_WS('-',date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y%m%d'),id);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date_id   
> -: | :---------
>  1 | 20190111-1
>  2 | 20190111-2
>  3 | 20190111-3
>  4 | 20190111-4
> ```

> ```
> show create table table1
> ```
>
> ```
> Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                            
> :----- | :-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (<br>  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br>  `date_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',<br>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)<br>) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

> ```
> alter table table1 alter column date_id DROP DEFAULT, ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> show create table table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> :----- | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> table1 | CREATE TABLE `table1` (<br>  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br>  `date_id` varchar(50),<br>  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)<br>) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=901c388775a026388d5158cc29bb07c9)*

Comment: looks like a new question to me.